# Accidentally re-installed wordpress

Tags: installation, shared-hosting

Big mistake. I accidentally installed wordpress over an existing install. I know that my data is probably still in the database. I'm hosted on bluehost.

What can I do to recover my instance?

Comment: Installing WP overwrites the database. You should check with your host to find out whether they have backups of the database itself. Many hosts do, even if you activate a paid backup service after the fact.

Comment: Also, if you're lucky, the first installation was done with a different *table prefix*  than the second, in which case, your old tables will (probably) still be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @WebElaine, I checked with Bluehost and they had backed up my wordpress a couple of days ago. Whew! I had them restore it and heavyweightsoftware.com is back in business.

Thanks, bluehost.com!